# Apple Developer Portal forces me to buy Mac Developer Program

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I am trying to renew my **iOS Developer Program**. Everything is fine with these steps:

[image: Img-1]
[image: Img-2]

But things get strange after this. When I click continue, it forces me to buy **Mac Developer Program** too. I couldn't remove it from basket even in store.

[image: Img-3]

Cleared the browser cache, tried with another computer. No solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write how my story ended.

I informed Apple Developer Support with e-mail. After their confirmation, I purchased both programs and requested a refund for Mac Developer Program.

They suggested an alternative way which I didn't follow: Manually purchasing only iOS Developer Program with e-mail order.